# Criteria for a limit to be a proper function

Tags: reference-request, cv.complex-variables, riemann-surfaces

This question is obviously broad; turning this broadness into something sharp is part of the problem.

Given a sequence of functions defined on a Riemann Surface $R$, valued in $\Bbb C^2$, what conditions are needed to make this sequence to converge uniformly on compact subsets to a function $h$ holomorphic and **proper**?

Does there exist some statement/theorem dealing with this?